# DataWeave - Get array of keys from nested Object

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I’m trying to come up with a DataWeave 2.0 function that receives value of type Any and returns an Array containing all the keys of the input value: `deepKeys(e: Any, keys: Array = []): Array<Key>`

A few examples:

- `deepKeys({hello: "hi", goodbye: "bye"})` returns `["hello", "goodbye"]`
- `deepKeys("hi")` returns `[]`
- `deepKeys(null)` returns `[]`
- `deepKeys({key1: "1", key2: {key3: "3"}})`  returns `["key1", "key2", "key3"]`
- `deepKeys([{key1: "1"}, {key1: "2"}, {key1: "3"}])` returns `["key1", "key1", "key1"]`

I would post a few things I've tried, but I don't think any of them are on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun deepKeys(value: Any, keys = []): Array<String> | Null = do {
    flatten([keys, 
    typeOf(value) as String match {
        case "Object" -> keysOf(value) reduce (v0, a0 = flatten([keys, keysOf(value)])) -> flatten([a0, deepKeys(value[v0], keys)])
        case "Array" -> value reduce (v1, a1 = []) -> flatten([a1, deepKeys(v1, keys)])
        else -> []
    }])
}
---
{
    t1: deepKeys({hello: "hi", goodbye: "bye"}),
    t2: deepKeys("hi"),
    t3: deepKeys(null),
    t4: deepKeys({key1: "1", key2: {key3: "3"}}),
    t5: deepKeys([{key1: "1"}, {key1: "2"}, {key1: "3"}]),
    t6: deepKeys([{key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: {key4: {key5: 5}}}])
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that works for your use-cases. I'm sure it can be prettier tho :D

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun getNestedValues(size: Number, e: Object | Array, keys: Array): Array = do {
    var newSize = size - 1
    ---
    if (newSize >= 0) (
        ((0 to newSize) as Array) reduce ((indx, acc=[]) -> (
            acc ++ deepKeys(e[indx], keys)
        ))
    ) else []
}
fun deepKeys (e: Any, keys: Array = []) = (
    e match {
        case is Object -> do {
            var thisKeys = keysOf(e)
            ---
            keys ++ thisKeys ++ getNestedValues(sizeOf(thisKeys), e, keys)
        }
        case is Array -> 
            getNestedValues(sizeOf(e), e, keys)
        else -> keys
    }
)
---
{
    t1: deepKeys({hello: "hi", goodbye: "bye"}),
    t2: deepKeys("hi"),
    t3: deepKeys(null),
    t4: deepKeys({key1: "1", key2: {key3: "3"}}),
    t5: deepKeys([{key1: "1"}, {key1: "2"}, {key1: "3"}]),
    t6: deepKeys([{key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: {key4: {key5: 5}}}])
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexandra, could you add a bit more explanation about your code in answer text? It would make it a better answer.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.